# GNUPLOT: dot plot with data depending dot size

Tags: scripting, plot, gnuplot

I am trying plot data sets consisting of 3 coordinates:
X-coordinate, x-coordinate and the number of occurrences.
example:

```
1 2 10 
3 1 2
3 2 1
```

I would like to draw for every line a dot at x,y with a diameter which is depending on the third value.

Is that possible with Gnuplot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a 2D plot with variable point size. See [the demo](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/pointsize.html).

**Example:**

```
plot 'dataFile.dat' u 1:2:3 w points lt 1 pt 10 ps variable
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically equivalent to the existing answer, just shorter:

```
plot 'dataFile.dat' with circles
```

Credit: [Gnuplot: plot with circles of a defined radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747573/gnuplot-plot-with-circles-of-a-defined-radius)