# Heat Map Histogram with gnuplot

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I'm working in Gnuplot, and I have a graph looking roughly like the following:

[image: Say]

If I want to have the color of the line change color depending on the curves's values, what's the most straightforward way to make that happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939200/line-plot-in-gnuplot-where-line-color-is-a-third-column-in-my-data-file/4115001#4115001)  help?

For example:

```
plot "./file.dat" u 1:2:2 with lines palette
```

where file.dat contains your data, the first column is the x axis and the second column is the y axis.

The repetition of the 2 indicates that the second column is also used for the colour.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a function (which i use quite a bit) on the matlab file exchange by Ken Garrard called [plot3k](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9519-color-coded-3d-scatterplot) that has this functionality that you're looking for. Mayhapes you could have a look at the implementation for hints for a gnuplot port.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these three articles is helpful:

http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/09/gradient-colored-curve-in-gnuplot0.html

http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/09/gradient-colored-curve-in-gnuplot1.html

http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/09/gradient-colored-curve-in-gnuplot2.html