# Gnuplot histogram with rgb colours from file

Tags: colors, gnuplot, histogram, rgb

I have a file formatted as follows:

```
A 12.0 255,20,147
B 325.0 255,255,0
C 134456.0 255,255,0
D 13869.0 0,0,0
E 4321.0 255,0,0
F 43676.0 165,42,42
```

I would like to produce a histogram where $2 is the height of the bar, $1 is the label (i.e.: it is written below the bar, under the x axis) and $3 is the RGB colour of the bar.
I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939200/line-plot-in-gnuplot-where-line-color-is-a-third-column-in-my-data-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315044/how-do-i-select-a-color-for-every-point-in-gnuplot-data-file) but I still can't figure out how to do what I just described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it: you first have to change the formatting of the rgb colours changing the commas to spaces, so that the new file becomes:

```
A 12.0 255 20 147
B 325.0 255 255 0
C 134456.0 255 255 0
D 13869.0 0 0 0
E 4321.0 255 0 0
F 43676.0 165 42 42
```

then you have to instruct gnuplot on how to parse the rgb colours:

```
rgb(r,g,b) = int(r)*65536 + int(g)*256 + int(b)
```

finally you can specify that you want column 1 to be the label (`xticlabels(1)`) and that you want variable colour (`lc rgb variable`), passing your `rgb` function the appropriate columns of your file (`rgb($3,$4,$5)`).
Summing it all up, the following commands worked for me:

```
set style fill solid
rgb(r,g,b) = int(r)*65536 + int(g)*256 + int(b)
plot 'hist_test.dat' using (column(0)):2:(0.5):(rgb($3,$4,$5)):xticlabels(1) w boxes lc rgb variable;
```