# How to make points one color when a third column equals zero, and another color otherwise, in Gnuplot?

Tags: variables, colors, gnuplot

I need to vary the point color for a row of values based on the color in one column. The data:

```
# x y z
1, 3, 0  
1, 5, 6  
3, 5, 2  
4, 5, 0
```

The color should be one value if the column is zero and a different color if the value in the third column is non-zero.

So, I'm assuming:

```
plot "./file.dat" u 1:2:3 with points palette
```

as found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4115001 will not quite work.

In the above example data, that gnuplot command provides three different colors instead of the two I'm looking for.

Comment: More general condition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717805/vary-point-color-in-gnuplot-based-on-value-of-one-column

Answer (score 31):

This is probably close to what you want:

```
set palette model RGB defined ( 0 'red', 1 'green' )
plot[0:5][0:6] "file.dat" u 1:2:( $3 == 0 ? 0 : 1 ) with points palette
```

You could go one step further and remove the "noise":

```
unset key
unset colorbox
plot[0:5][0:6] "file.dat" u 1:2:( $3 == 0 ? 0 : 1 ) with points pt 7 ps 3 palette
```

if only the differentiation between zero and non-zero matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the palette by

```
set palette defined (-0.1 "blue", 0 "red", 0.1 "blue")
```

Comment: This puts red at around three and blue at 0 and 6 and thus does not achieve the OP's goal. I have built on your idea, see below!