# vary point color based on column value for multiple data blocks gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, rgb

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717805/vary-point-color-in-gnuplot-based-on-value-of-one-column) one, from which I was able to learn a lot.  However, I am working with multiple data blocks, like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 0
4 3 0


4 5 7
2 3 0
4 5 0
5 6 7
```

and I am plotting them like this:

```
plot "file.txt" index 0 u 1:2 w points pt 1,\
     "file.txt" index 1 u 1:2 w points pt 2
```

which creates 2 different sets of points, each a different color.  Now, my goal is to modify this script so that if the 3rd data column is 0, the color of the point will become black.  I would like for the other points to remain the colors that they currently are though (meaning different from one another).  I have done this:

```
set palette model RGB defined ( 0 'black', 1 'green' )
unset colorbox
plot file index 0 u 1:2:( $3 == 0 ? 0 : 1 ) w points pt 1 palette,\
     file index 1 u 1:2:( $3 == 0 ? 0 : 1 ) w points pt 2 palette
```

This does exactly what I want, except of course both sets are now plotted in green.  Is there any way to plot the black ones as desired, but also make each index a different color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work to define an extra point in the palette:

```
set palette model RGB defined ( 0 'black', 1 'green', 2 'red')
unset colorbox
plot file index 0 u 1:2:( $3 == 0 ? 0 : 1 ) w points pt 1 palette,\
     file index 1 u 1:2:( $3 == 0 ? 0 : 2 ) w points pt 2 palette
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is what the special "variable" color is for:

```
plot 'test.dat' i 0 u 1:2:($3 == 0? 0:1) w p pt 1 lc variable,\
     'test.dat' i 1 u 1:2:($3 == 0? 0:2) w p pt 2 lc variable
```

`variable` in this context says to use the color of whatever "style index" was given in the third column.  I set filters on the 3rd column variable which transforms the third column into a constant (1 or 2) if the data in that column isn't 0.

Another, less direct approach (which works since you're using points) is:

```
plot 'test.dat' i 0 u 1:($3 == 0? 1/0: $2) w p pt 1 lc rgb "red",\
     'test.dat' i 0 u 1:($3 == 0? $2:1/0) w p pt 1 lc rgb "black,\
     'test.dat' i 1 u 1:($3 == 0? 1/0: $2) w p pt 1 lc rgb "green",\
     'test.dat' i 1 u 1:($3 == 0? $2:1/0) w p pt 1 lc rgb "black,\
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question on this if that is ok.  Let me know if I should post it as a separate question.  I am now plotting things either red, green, or black by referencing the indices 0, 1, and 2.  My new question is, can I plot everything whose 3rd column has non-zero value with a color gradient (using something like set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10) and then if the 3rd column has value zero, plot it in black?

Comment: @whatsherface -- If I understand you correctly, that should be possible by just combining my answer and the answer by andyras

Comment: I believe that will work to give me discrete colors, but I would like to use a gradient based on the data of the 3rd column.  As I understand it, ($8 == 0.0 ? 0 : 1) means: if the 8th column is zero, plot the color that is referenced by "0" (black), if not, plot the color that is referenced by "1".  What I need is: if zero, plot black, if not, use the gradient rgbformulae 33,13,10.  Can I reference a color gradient using a single index?

Comment: @whatsherface -- Post a new question I think.  I'm pretty sure I can answer this one, but doing it in comments won't do it justice.  (and I bet you can give a better explanation outside of comments as well).