# Custom legend (or text) gnuplot

Tags: colors, gnuplot, legend

I have a file with 3 columns, the first 2 are the position x y and the 3rd one I use it for define the color so I have something like this:

```
set palette model RGB defined ( 1 'black', 2 'blue', 3 'green', 4 'red')
unset colorbox

plot "file" u 2:1:3 w points pt 14 ps 2 palette, "file2" u 2:1:3 w points pt 14 ps 2        palette
```

Now the question: Is it possible to have a proper legend with this kind of point and COLOR?.
Since the points will have different colors (according to the pallete) I want to specify what means each color in the legend.

The only solution I was thinking was to write somewhere in the plot some text with the character of the point (in this case pt 14) and specify the color... but is not really a solution right?

So please help!

Comment: Usually the `colorbox`, which you unset, is meant for this.

Comment: what do you mean? I am not an expert at all =)

Comment: Remove the `unset colorbox` part from your script and you'll have an association value <-> color. Or do you have only a few color values and each color has a distinct meaning?

Comment: yes I have only 4 values and for each one, a color. Different color means different things, and I want to have that in the legend. But if I add title 'something' it will have the correct symbol but not the color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no option for this, you need to fiddle a bit. Here is YAGH (Yet another gnuplot hack) ;)

Assuming that your values are equidistantly spaced, you can use the `'+'` special filename with the `labels` plotting style.

To show only the custom key, consider the following example:

```
labels="first second third fourth"
set xrange[0:1] # must be set for '+'
set yrange[0:1]
set samples words(labels)   # number of colors to use
key_x = 0.8     # x-value of the points, must be given in units of the x-axis
key_y = 0.8
key_dy = 0.05
set palette model RGB defined ( 1 'black', 2 'blue', 3 'green', 4 'red')
unset colorbox
plot '+' using (key_x):(key_y + $0*key_dy):(word(labels, int($0+1))):0 \
    with labels left offset 1,-0.1 point pt 7 palette t ''
```

This gives (with 4.6.4):

[image]

As the `set samples` doesn't affect the data plots, you can integrate this directly in your plot command:

```
...
unset key
plot "file" u 2:1:3 w points pt 14 ps 2 palette, \
     "file2" u 2:1:3 w points pt 14 ps 2 palette, \
     '+' using (key_x):(key_y - $0*key_dy):(word(labels, int($0+1))):0 \
         with labels left offset 1,-0.1 point pt 14 ps 2 palette
```

But you need to set a proper xrange, yrange and the values of `key_x`, `key_y` and `key_dy`.

This is not the most intuitive way, but it works :)

Comment: Thank you, very useful. I adjusted it a little bit to be more dynamic in respect to scaling the axis:  
key_x = x_range - x_range / 10.0  etc...

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative solution posted here:
[Using Gnuplot to plot point colors conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993538/using-gnuplot-to-plot-point-colors-conditionally/14993972#14993972)

Essentially you plot once without a legend entry, then make dummy plots (with no data) for each point color/label.

Comment: Yes, combined with iterations and `lc palette frac` it should work fine: `labels="A B C D"; plot 'file' u 2:1:3 w p pt 14 ps 2 palette, for [i=1:4] '' u (NaN):(NaN) w p pt 14 ps 2 lc palette frac (i/3.0) title word(i)`.