# Plot new series based on value within column

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Lets assume we have a data like :

```
1383.77224864627    1910.27446956287    13
2022.08962783969    1870.75968662608    13
2244.59435149955    2334.43843428841    13
3223.73010669775    2409.90834407782    15
708.364446053354    3199.82702811616    15
1190.6942303025     2634.33363259192    15
1749.15599203783    2716.76870380272    19
2227.80906774024    3119.99529267007    19
```

Is it possible to plot series, based on values in the 3rd column ?

Desired result in this example would be to have 3 series with different colors on one plot.

I'm aware that I can create new series with :

```
plot 'datafile' using col1:col2, '' using col1:col3
```

or by using new line between series in datafile but thats not I would like to do.

Thanks ! 
Edit: I'm using gnuplot version 5.0

Comment: Are you saying that you want col3 on the x axis and cols 1 and 3 on the y axis? If not, pls explain what the outcome should look like.

Comment: I want to plot a scatter chart, where first and second column is the (x,y), and the 3rd  value distinguish a series. Using the example  from question, I would like to have a 3 series of points plotted - every series with different color - 3 points would come from series '13', 3 points from series '15', and 2 points from series '19'.

Comment: Does [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717805/how-to-make-points-one-color-when-a-third-column-equals-zero-and-another-color/8728339#8728339) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [my 2012 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717805/how-to-make-points-one-color-when-a-third-column-equals-zero-and-another-color/8728339#8728339) and my understanding of what you want, this should help:

```
set palette defined ( 13 "blue", 15 "red", 19 "green")
unset key
unset colorbox
plot [500:3500][1800:3500] "x" u 1:2:3 with points palette ps 3 pt 5
```

which yields

[image]

EDIT:

One could also define a continuous palette and let the actual colors be allocated depending upon their value within that scale. In practice:

```
set palette defined ( 0 "blue", 20 "green", 40 "red")
unset key
set colorbox                              # for demo purpose
plot [500:3500][1800:3500] "x" u 1:2:3 with points palette ps 3 pt 7
```

which brings

[image]

for the given data set. Colors will change when new series is added.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to achieve, but there is no way to *not* use custom palette ? I have like 25 possible series, so I need to define entirely new palette that consist of 25 colors each time ?

Comment: See edited example, although I wonder whether such a plot provides enough clarity - but that's your call...

Comment: I do not see any changes in your post. This will be a cluster coloring plot, so it will work fine :)

Comment: As you said, the scale does not work - too many similar colors  :)  https://www2.uni-hamburg.de/Wiss/FB/15/Sustainability/schneider/gnuplot/colors.htm Nice list of colors to use. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You would need to filter the datafile first and then plot individual parts separately:

```
#prepare the command responsible for filtering the data file of interest
#select all rows the value in the 3rd column of which is equal to val
filterData(fname, val)=sprintf("<gawk '$3==%d' %s", val, fname)

#show individual dependencies in one plot
plot for [sval in "13 15"] \
    filterData('datafile.dat', int(sval)) w lp t sprintf('value %s', sval)
```

This would give you:
[image]