# Gnuplot - plotting series based on label in third column

Tags: gnuplot

I have data in the format:

```
1  1  A
2  3  ab
1  2  A
3  3  x
4  1  x
2  3  A
```

and so on. The third column indicates the series. That is in the case above there are 3 distinct data series, one designated A, another designated ab and last designated x. Is there a way to plot the three data series from such data structure in gnuplot without using eg. `awk`? The difficulty here is that the number of categories (here denoted A, ab, x) is quite large and it is not feasible to write them out by hand.
I was thinking along the lines:

`plot data u 1:2:3 w dots`

but that does not work and I get `warning: Skipping data file with no valid points` (I tried quoted and unquoted version of the third column). [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129608/plot-new-series-based-on-value-within-column) has to manually define the palette which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of work you can make a list of unique categories from within gnuplot without using external tools. The following code snippet first assembles a list of the entire third column of the data file, and then loops over it to generate a list of unique category names. If memory use or processing time become an issue then one could probably combine these steps and avoid forming a single string with the entire third column.

```
delimiter = "#"    # some character that does not appear in category name
categories = ""

stats "test.dat" using (categories = categories." ".delimiter.strcol(3).delimiter) nooutput

unique_categories = ""
do for [cat in categories] {
   if (strstrt (unique_categories, cat) ==0) {
      unique_categories = unique_categories." ".cat
   }
}

set xrange[0:5]
set yrange [0:4]
plot for [cat in unique_categories] "test.dat" using 1:(delimiter.strcol(3).delimiter eq cat ? $2 : NaN) title cat[2:strlen(cat)-1]
```

[image]

Take a look at the contents of the string variables `categories` and `unique_categories` to get a better idea of what this code does.