# How can I make the line color of a fitted function change with y?

Tags: gnuplot

So if I have a set of data, say "GnuTest.dat" and I fit f(x) = a*x**2 to it, then plot them both, is there a way to have the color of f(x) vary with f(x)?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
set autoscale
set term aqua size 700,500
set palette positive nops_allcF maxcolors 1 gamma 1.5 color model HSV
set palette defined ( 0 0 1 1 , 1 1 1 1 )
unset log
set termoption enhanced
set xtics 1
set mxtics 4
set ytics 1
set mytics 4
set title "Gnuplot Script Template"
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
set size ratio -1
a = 1
b=0.5
f(x) = a*x**2 +b
stats "GnuTest.rtf" u 1:2
print STATS_max_y;
fit f(x) "GnuTest.rtf" using 1:2 via a,b
plot "GnuTest.rtf" using 1:2 title "Gnu Test" w points pt 7, f(x) t "ax^2 + b fit" w lines lc variable
```

So in theory, I would like to vary the color along the hue scale between the minimum and maximum f(x) values. I've tried putting `:(f(x)/STATS_max_y)` or something similar after `using 1:2`, but I always get errors like "x not defined" or "; expected". Am I missing something obvious?

**Edit:** This is how my plot looks following @Christoph's advice. I have `set termoption solid` and used `lt -1`.

[image: GnuScriptTemplate]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939200/line-plot-in-gnuplot-where-line-color-is-a-third-column-in-my-data-file?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use a variable linecolor with a function, you must use the `'+'` special filename. That allows you to use the `using` option, which is required for use with variable linecolor. Note, that this is not related at all to fitting.

Here is a minimal, runnable script:

```
set palette defined ( 0 0 1 1 , 1 1 1 1 ) color model HSV gamma 1.5
set xrange[0:10]
f(x) = x**2
plot '+' using 1:(f($1)):(f($1)) with lines linecolor palette lw 3 notitle
```

The result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]

Note, that you cannot use `maxcolors 1`, as this gives (at least for me) only black.

Comment: Thank you, solves the main part of my problem (hence accepted). However in my terminal (`aquaterm`), I can only get a dashed line no matter how much fiddling I seem to do with `linetype`. `maxcolors` should have been 0, just one of the things I was playing around with when trying to find my own solution!

Comment: I've never used aquaterm, so this is kind of guessing. You should be able to use only solid lines with `set termoption solid`. Also, linetypes -1 should be always solid.