# Gnuplot: Colour proportional to y-value for builtin functions

Tags: gnuplot

Does anyone know of an easy way to plot, say, `sin(x)`, such that the colour changes depending on the y-value?

```
set palette defined (0 "blue", 1 "green")
plot sin(x) lc palette frac abs(sin(x))
```

Also doesn't work!

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make the line color of a fitted function change with y?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255915/how-can-i-make-the-line-color-of-a-fitted-function-change-with-y)

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your comment before posting my answer. Indeed it's the same problem that calls for the same solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the special filename `'+'` to internally generates a list of values (x values as $1) and then use those values to plot what you want using the third column to play with your palette.

```
set palette defined (0 "blue", 1 "green")
plot '+' u ($1):(sin($1)):(abs(sin($1))) with lines palette
```

[image: Snapshoot of my solution]