# GnuPlot line plot from data points, z interpolated color?

Tags: graph, plot, gnuplot

I have a data file with x, y, and z datums--basically x,y locations with
z representing attenuation at that location.

The answer to a question like [Line plot in GnuPlot where line color is a third column in my data file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939200/line-plot-in-gnuplot-where-line-color-is-a-third-column-in-my-data-file) using
palette defined (with palette z) is very
close, except that each line segment is set to a single color along its length.

Is there a
way to have the Z value interpolated (linear is fine) along each segment, so
the attenuation values are a smooth gradient rather than jumping values
at each segment boundary?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `set dgrid3d` to interpolate a given data set. Consider the data file `test.dat` with the content

```
1 2 1
2 3 2
1 1 2
```

Plot this with

```
set dgrid3d 30,30 splines
set ticslevel 0
set hidden3d
splot 'test.dat' matrix w l lc palette lw 3
```

to get

[image]

If this works also in your case depends on several other factors, like number of data points or if you don't want to create a new grid, but retain the original grid, and only smooth the colors. In the latter case you must write an external script to prepare your data in an appropriate way.

Comment: Is there any way to get dgrid3d's interpolation of z, but applied to an output which looks more like "plot 'test.dat' w l lc palette z"?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you mean.