# change the color of points in gnuplot with C

Tags: c, colors, gnuplot, point

Can I do such a thing on gnuplot that it works?
when buffer[i] == max change the color of the point

```
  fprintf(gnuplot, "if (\"%d\" == \"%d\") plot '-' with lines lw2; else plot '-' with lines lw 1 \n", buffer[i], max);

     for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++)
    { 

        fprintf(gnuplot, "%d %d \n", i,buffer[i]); 
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's different

Comment: Possible duplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939200/line-plot-in-gnuplot-where-line-color-is-a-third-column-in-my-data-file/ Just google for examples, I think you may find a lot.