# Gnuplot: plot with circles of a defined radius

Tags: plot, geometry, gnuplot

I know on gnuplot you can plot some data with circles as the plot points:

```
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2 ls 1 with circles
```

How do I then set the size of the circles? I want to plot several sets of data but with different size circles for each data set.

Answer (score 12):

If you have a third column in your data, the third column specifies the size of the circles.  In your case, you could have the third column have the same value for all the points in each data set.  For example:

```
plot '-' with circles
1 1 0.2
e
```

will plot a circle at (1,1) with radius 0.2.  Note that the radius is in the same units as the data. (The special file name '-' lets you input data directly; typing 'e' ends the input. Type `help special` at the gnuplot console for more info.)

You can look [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/circles.html) for more ideas of how to use circles.

Comment: Fancy -- I didn't know this one off the top of my head.  I guess I haven't plotted with circles before.  I that a 4.3+ feature?  I always resorted to plotting `with points pointsize variable` (Yuck!).  (+1).

Comment: My program produces data in 2 columns. I want just a constant size to the circles for each data set. Does that mean I need to add a 3rd column of identical numbers to my dataset? Is there not another way?

Comment: @Eddy -- you can do something like `plot 'datafile' u 1:2:(1.5) w circles`.  This will make circles with a radius of 1.5 (and you only need 2 columns of data in the datafile).  How are your datasets separated in the file?  If they're separated by 2 blank lines, you can use pseudo-column -2 to pick out the index number.

Comment: @mgilson I couldn't get it to work. I don't get a circle at each x,y coordinate, but instead get a load of circles stacked on top of each other and the x-axis ranges from -1.5 to 1.5. My data is just 2 columns, separated by a space.

Comment: @Eddy: Are your data values very small?  mgilson's value of 1.5 for the radius was just an example; you should scale it such that the circles will be a reasonable size.  If your data values are, for example, on the order of 0.01, the radius of your circles should be something like 0.001 or 0.0001.

Comment: @andyras: Thanks, yes my data values were on the order of 10^(-9) so I needed to scale the radius of my circles appropiately.

Comment: A few words about the `plot '-'` feature could help to figure out what is going on here: a "data input console" is opened...

Comment: One caveat: plot marker circles will match the X scale of your plot and ignore the Y scale of your plot. So if you want to illustrate precise geometry, you need 'set size ratio -1'

Answer (score 8):

I used:

```
plot "file" using 1:2:($2*0+10) with circles
```

This will fake a the third column specifying the sizes - it is probably possible to write it simpler, but this worked for me.

Comment: `using 1:2:(10)` would be enough.