# How to get circles with specific radii in pixels in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

When plotting data using circles, the radii of the circles depend on the data size (i.e. X/Y ranges) according to the answers for the question in [Gnuplot: plot with circles of a defined radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747573/gnuplot-plot-with-circles-of-a-defined-radius) .

Is it possible to define a screen delimited radii for the circles instead? That is, I want all the circles to have a specific radius in pixels no matter they size nor the X/Y ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are just looking for a plot symbol in the shape of a circle? Then use the usual `points` style with `pointtype 6` (empty circles) or `7` (solid circles), and specify the `pointsize` scale factor (1 corresponds to default)

```
plot [0:2] '+' using 1:1 with points pointtype 6 pointsize 1, \
           '+' using 1:(sqrt($1)) with points pointsize 1.5 pointtype 7
```